Jacobi-Trudi-like identity with dual characters
If $\lambda$ is a partition with at most $n$ parts, let $s_\lambda$ be the corresponding Schur polynomial in $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. In particular, for $a \geq 0$, $s_{a}$ is the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial $h_a(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, the character of the symmetric power $\operatorname{Sym}^a V$ of the standard representation of $\operatorname{SL}_n$. Also, $s_{\underbrace{a,\ldots,a}_{n-1}} = (x_1 \cdots x_n)^a h_a(x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}) =: h_a^\vee$ is the character of the dual $\operatorname{Sym}^a V^*$.
Look at partitions $\lambda = (a+b,\underbrace{a,\ldots,a}_{n-2},0)$ where all but the first and last parts are equal. Numerical evidence suggests that
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1} \tag{1}
s_{a+b,\underbrace{a,\ldots,a}_{n-2}} \stackrel{?}= h_a^\vee h_b - (x_1\cdots x_n) h_{a-1}^\vee h_{b-1}.
\end{equation}
This has a resemblance to the Jacobi-Trudi identity
$$
s_{a,b} = h_a h_b - h_{a+1} h_{b-1},
$$
but I don't see an easy way to get from one to the other. Is \eqref{eq:1} a case of a well-known result?

This is Corollary 4.30 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.06128v5 .

Multiply $s_{a+b,a,\dots,a}$ by $(x_1\cdots x_n)^{-a}$ to get the character of the rational representation of highest weight $(b,\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-2},-a)$. In general every highest weight is of the form $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r,0,\dots,0,-\mu_s,\dots,-\mu_1)$ where $r+s \le n$ and for simplicity let me call its character $s_{[\lambda;\mu]}$, which we might call a rational Schur polynomial. There's a good theory for the "stable" representation theory of these rational Schur polynomials (but some things in certain formulas get complicated if $n$ is not sufficiently large). In any case, we get a formula
$s_{[\lambda;\mu]} = \sum_{\nu} (-1)^{|\nu|} s_{\lambda/\nu} s_{\mu/\nu^T}^\vee$
where the sum is over all partitions $\nu$, $\nu^T$ is its transpose, and $s^\vee$ will mean the character of the dual representation.
You're interested in $s_{[b;a]}$, in which case your formula (1) follows since the only $\nu$ which give nonzero contributions are $\nu=0$ and $\nu=(1)$. Here, $n$ large enough just means $n\ge 2$.
One possible reference is "On the decomposition of tensor products of the representations of the classical groups: By means of the universal characters" by Koike: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870889900042
See Theorem 2.3. There the notation $[\lambda,\mu]_{GL}$ is used instead of $s_{[\lambda;\mu]}$. Technically, the formula is proved in the "universal character ring", i.e., a setting where $n$ is always assumed sufficiently large. But to specialize to finitely many variables you can use Proposition 2.2.
You might also be interested in Definition 2.1 which gives a determinantal expression for these rational Schur polynomials, though as far as I know it does not come from Jacobi-Trudi. These are sometimes also called "composite Schur polynomials", or at least I've seen their super analogues called as such in the Lie superalgebra literature ("composite supersymmetric Schur polynomials").
